# How to set context root of an application in JBoss?

Tags: spring-mvc, jboss, spring-security, jboss-4.2.x

Hi every one i am new to Jboss server,i had a problem of setting context root of an application in JBoss-4.2.2.GA server.my application is done using spring MVC+Spring security.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may also have to remove the $JBOSS_HOME/server/default/deploy/jboss-web.deployer/ROOT.war/ directory and then add then add the above jboss-web.xml to the WEB-INF directory of your web application.

See also:

- http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Portal_Platform/4.3/html/Reference_Guide/configuration-contextroot.html

Answer (score 0):

If you use a pom.xml, try to change the `artifactId` of your project to your project name, i hope this will be helpful for you.

Comment: I tried to change the artifactId but it isn't working for me. I used the Spring Template Project to create the Spring MVC application in SpringSourceTolSuite